# Firebase Storage on NodeJS Client

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have setup Firebase Storage to allow authenticated users to upload files. However, in my client which is powered by NodeJS, Firebase.storage is not available.

The documentation tells me to use Google Cloud Storage, but I can not find a way to authenticate with Cloud Storage in my clients.

How can I upload files in this situation?

Comment: Authenticate what or whom?  What SDK are you using?

Comment: Where is your code running (client or server)? What documentation are you referring to? The more details you provide and reference links the better the answers.

Comment: I want to upload files to Firebase Storage using a NodeJS client. I am using the NodeJS SDK (https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase), the code is running on the client. I can install other SDKs if necessary...